# How to set color to uiviewcontroller before loading the app in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

How to set color to UIViewController before loading the app in iOS with Swift?

In other words , I want to change background of first image shown when app loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to set color to uiviewcontroller:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**set image to view**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage(named: "imageName")!)   
}
```

**set color to view**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to set `color` to `ViewController` first time load app.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor WhiteColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `viewWillAppear` method to set color

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) // No need for semicolon
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project has a `Launchscreen.storyboard` file, in Interface builder:

1. Select its view,
2. Select the Attributes Inspector in the right pane,
3. Set the background color attribute of the view to the color you want.

This is the launch screen that appears before the app loads fully. If you want the next screen to be the same color, too, do as others suggested below and set the `backgroundColor` property of `self.view` within `viewDidLod()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a default screen when you start your application, what is shown depends on your implementation:

- You can use an **image**: in this case, in order to change the background, you need to change the image itself.
- You can use a **storyboard/xib**: in this case you can change the background of your screen from Interface Builder, changing the background color attribute of your view, or programmatically with the code below

**ObjectiveC**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```